# Django model: downloading image from ftp server

Tags: python, xml, django, ftp

first of all sorry for my English, it's not my mother tongue. I'm writing a XML parser in python 2.7. There are a links for images, that are downloading and saving into DB, it works fine with http, but I need to download them from ftp server.
Here is function that is calling from parser:

```
q=sa_web_images.objects.create(
    web_image_url=iphoto, 
    web_item_id=wi_id,
    non_repeat=non_repeat
)
q.get_remote_image()
```

Where 'iphoto' is a link, for example: ftp://example.com/image.jpg.

And here is function that save it into DB:

```
def get_remote_image(self):
    if self.web_image_url and not self.web_image:
        result = urllib.urlretrieve(self.web_image_url)
        self.web_image.save(
            os.path.basename(self.web_image_url),
            File(open(result[0]))
            )
        self.save()
```

I know username and password for ftp access, but I don't know, how should I insert them into code, can someone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

username and password can be supplied to urllib by specifying them in the url, like for example

```
    result = urllib.urlretrieve("ftp://user:password@example.com/image.jpg")
```